# strange behavior of RGB values in non retina

Tags: ios, rgb

I am creating a bitmap in one of the iOS apps in which I draw something on screen and capture the context using the following code :

```
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
NSUInteger width    = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height   = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel    = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow      = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

unsigned char *rawData     = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * bytesPerPixel, sizeof(unsigned char));
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

This data I later use to check if the pixels are black or not. The problem I am facing is when I draw something and its black in color (RGB value 0,0,0) , the RGB value for that pixel is correctly detected in retina displays but in non retina its not giving the correct value.It does not give me 0,0,0 in non retina. Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of your UIImage. It may be different in non-retina display and hence you may check the color of another pixel if it's non retina display on the device.